# Проверка на пустой запрос (LocalDB)- C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

У меня есть ComboBox1 и ComboBox2. Данные для ComboBox берутся из LocalDB и эти два элемента управления связанны. В одном море(ComboBox1) отображается, в другом район(ComboBox2). Не в каждом море добавлены районы, поэтому надо проверить `SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(queryString2, connection);` на пустой запрос и если запрос пуст сделать `comboBox2.Enabled = false;`
Сам код :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == null) return;
    string SeaID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string queryString2 = String.Format("SELECT Id, Area FROM dbo.Area WHERE seaID ='" + SeaID + "'");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ПАК_ИП_ОЭБ_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(queryString2, connection);
            if (cmd2 != null)
            {
                DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                da2.Fill(tbl2);
                this.comboBox2.DataSource = tbl2;
                this.comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Area";// столбец для отображения
                this.comboBox2.ValueMember = "Id";//столбец с id
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
                comboBox2.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("1");
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
                comboBox2.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Но тут всегда срабатывает условие `if (cmd2 != null)`, на какое его стоить поменять, чтоб пустые запросы не обрабатывались и попадали в

```
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
    comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
    comboBox2.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: `cmd2 != null` - всегда верно!
`tbl2.Rows.Count==0` - ответ пустой

Comment: Дмитрий Чистик - спасибо if (tbl2.Rows.Count != 0) ... срабатывает)

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ из комментариев (сори отдыхал):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == null) return;
    string SeaID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    comboBox3.Enabled = true;
    string queryString2 = string.Format("SELECT [Id], [Area] FROM [dbo].[Area] WHERE [seaID]='" + SeaID + "'", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(queryString2, connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2))
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();
                da2.Fill(tbl2);
                comboBox2.DataSource = tbl2;
                comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Area";// столбец для отображения
                comboBox2.ValueMember = "Id";//столбец с id
                comboBox2.Enabled = tbl2.Rows.Count > 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                comboBox2.DataSource = null;
                comboBox2.Enabled = false;
            }
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sring в string поправил.......это исправил "SELECT [Id], [Area] FROM [dbo].[Area] WHERE [seaID]={0}",на это)))))))"SELECT [Id], [Area] FROM [dbo].[Area] WHERE [seaID]='" + SeaID + "'"........спасибо заменил код)